# Calculate the sum of two numbers and "return" it by using a void function in C with a pointer as parameter

Tags: c, pointers

So basically I'd like to sum two numbers and return their value while using a void function in C. I know this is easy peasy by using a normal function returning an int or a numeric type but I wanna work on my pointer knowledge.

I tried creating a pointer inside main() and then passing it as an argument to the void function. Then I calculated my sum in a new int variable and assigned the pointer to point to that specific variable. The problem is I can't "retrieve" it or "find" that area of memory in the main function.

Here's what I've tried:

```
void testFunction(int a,int b, int *x)
{
   int c=a+b;
   x=&c; 
}

int main()
{
  int n1=7;
  int n2=90;
  int *pointerParam;
  testFunction(n1, n2, pointerParam);
   
  printf("Value of pointer is %d\n", *pointerParam);
}
```

It just exits with an error code, it does nothing. If I try to printf *x inside the function, it does work so I know that part at least works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems with the code as it is shown.

The main problem is probably that you misunderstand how emulation of pass-by-reference works in C.

For it to work you need to pass a pointer to the variable that should be set. This is done using the pointer-to operator `&`. You also need to *dereference* the pointer, to set the variable the pointer is pointing to.

Putting it together your program should look something like this (simplified):

```
void testFunction(int a,int b, int *x)
{
    // Assign to where `x` is pointing
    *x = a + b;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n1 = 7;
    int n2 = 90;
    int result;  // Where the result should be written

    // Pass a pointer to the `result` variable, so the function can write to it
    testFunction(n1, n2, &result);
}
```

Comment: I would add that if you also want to use a pointer in `main`, you could allocate `pointerParam` dynamically using `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

I will show you a program that is no more than a set of **printf()** and your function. Maybe the program's output helps in showing these pointers, arrays and integers *things*.

### The example

Consider these variables

```
    int  n[4]      = {10, 20, -30, -40};
    int  v1        = 0;
    int  v2        = 0;
    int* a_pointer = NULL;
```

`int*` is a pointer to an `int`, that's the meaning of the asterisk in the declaration. In this context the asterisk is called the *dereference operator* or the *indirection operator*. But the asterisk also is the multiplication operator in C. ;)

Now `a_pointer` points to nothing, the meaning of the `NULL`.

But `a_pointer` is there to hold an address of something, of an `int`. The way of getting such *address of something* is the *address of* operator, the `&`, that also has an alternate life as the `bitwise and` operator in C. Things of life.

In `printf()` the `%p` specifier shows an address. This

```
    printf("\naddress of v1 is %p\n", &v1);
    printf("address of v2 is %p\n", &v2);
    printf("address of array n[0] is %p\n", n);
    printf("address of array n[0] is %p\n", 1 + n);
    printf("address of array n[0] is %p\n", 2 + n);
    printf("address of array n[0] is %p\n\n", 3 + n);
```

shows (in a 32-bits compilation)

```
address of v1 is 008FFDA0
address of v2 is 008FFD9C
address of array n[0] is 008FFDA4
address of array n[1] is 008FFDA8
address of array n[2] is 008FFDAC
address of array n[3] is 008FFDB0
```

And you will see the reason the program prints these lines in the code below...

This line

```
    a_pointer = &v1;
```

takes the address of `v1` and assign it to the pointer `a_pointer`.
Now `a_pointer` is pointing to something, to `v1`, and you can use it in your function. These lines are equivalent

```
    testFunction(n[0], n[3], &v1);
```

and

```
    testFunction(n[0], n[3], a_pointer);
```

In these lines

```
    testFunction(n[0], n[3], &v1);
    printf("n[0] = %d, n[3] = %d, sum in v1 is %d\n", n[0], n[3], v1);
    printf(
        "p points to v1. value is %4d, address is %p\n\n", *a_pointer,
        a_pointer);
```

you see the use of the pointer to access the value it points to, using the *dereference* operator in the `printf()`.

Follow the program along to see a few uses of this.

In particular, see these lines

```
    a_pointer = n + 3;
    printf(
        "\np points now to n[3]. value is %4d, address is %p\n",
        *a_pointer, a_pointer);
```

to see the thing C is made for: address memory easily. `n` is `int[4]`, an array of `int`. `a_pointer` is a pointer to `int`. And the language knows that when you write `a_pointer = n + 3` that it needs to add to the address of `n`, an `int[]`, the size of 3 `int` variables, and assign it to the pointer, so `*a_pointer` is `n[3]`and it is used to call `testFunction()` in

```
    testFunction(n[1], n[2], n + 3);
```

#### program output

```
n[] is [10,20,-30,-40], v1 is 0 v2 is 0

address of v1 is 00CFFA9C
address of v2 is 00CFFA98
address of array n[0] is 00CFFAA0
address of array n[1] is 00CFFAA4
address of array n[2] is 00CFFAA8
address of array n[3] is 00CFFAAC

n[0] = 10, n[3] = -40, sum in v1 is -30
p points to v1. value is  -30, address is 00CFFA9C

p now points to v2. value is    0, address is 00CFFA98
n[0] = 10, n[1] = 20, sum in v2 is 30
n[] is [10,20,-30,-40], v1 is -30 v2 is 30

p now points to v1. value is  -30, address is 00CFFA9C
n[] is [10,20,-30,-40], v1 is -30 v2 is 30

now makes n[3] = n[1] + n[2] using testFunction()
n[] is [10,20,-30,-10], v1 is -30 v2 is 30

p points now to n[3]. value is  -10, address is 00CFFAAC
```

#### the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

show(int[4], int, int);
void testFunction(int, int, int*);

int main(void)
{
    int  n[4]      = {10, 20, -30, -40};
    int  v1        = 0;
    int  v2        = 0;
    int* a_pointer = NULL;

    show(n, v1, v2);
    printf("\naddress of v1 is %p\n", &v1);
    printf("address of v2 is %p\n", &v2);
    printf("address of array n[0] is %p\n", n);
    printf("address of array n[1] is %p\n", 1 + n);
    printf("address of array n[2] is %p\n", 2 + n);
    printf("address of array n[3] is %p\n\n", 3 + n);
    a_pointer = &v1;
    testFunction(n[0], n[3], &v1);
    printf("n[0] = %d, n[3] = %d, sum in v1 is %d\n", n[0], n[3], v1);
    printf(
        "p points to v1. value is %4d, address is %p\n\n", *a_pointer,
        a_pointer);

    a_pointer = &v2;
    printf(
        "p now points to v2. value is %4d, address is %p\n", *a_pointer,
        a_pointer);
    testFunction(n[0], n[1], &v2);
    printf("n[0] = %d, n[1] = %d, sum in v2 is %d\n", n[0], n[1], v2);
    show(n, v1, v2);

    a_pointer = &v1;
    printf(
        "\np now points to v1. value is %4d, address is %p\n", *a_pointer,
        a_pointer);

    show(n, v1, v2);
    printf("\nnow makes n[3] = n[1] + n[2] using testFunction()\n");
    testFunction(n[1], n[2], n + 3);
    show(n, v1, v2);

    a_pointer = n + 3;
    printf(
        "\np points now to n[3]. value is %4d, address is %p\n",
        *a_pointer, a_pointer);

    return 0;
};

show(int n[4], int v1, int v2)
{
    printf(
        "n[] is [%d,%d,%d,%d], v1 is %d v2 is %d\n", n[0], n[1], n[2],
        n[3], v1, v2);
};

void testFunction(int a, int b, int* sum)
{
    *sum = a + b;
    return;
}
```

I will not go into religious discussions here, but you may find easier to understand the meaning of the declarions if you write

```
    int*    some_int = NULL;
```

instead of

```
    int    *some_int = NULL;
```

you declare a name, and the name is `some_int`. The compiler will tell you that `some_int` is `int*`, its type. The fact that `*some_int` is an `int` is a consequence of the application of an operator to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You lacked just to understand how pointers are managed, but you were almost correct:

```
/* this is almost correct, you could have just said: *x = a + b; */
void testFunction(int a,int b, int *x)
{
   int c=a+b;
   *x=c; /* the pointed to value is what we are assigning */
}

int main()
{
  int n1=7;
  int n2=90;
  int result;       /* vvvvvvv this is the important point */
  testFunction(n1, n2, &result); /* you pass the address of result as the required pointer */
   
  printf("Value of pointer is %d\n", result);
}
```